# In TypeScript, when to use <> and when to use :

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm not understanding when I should use `<>` and when I should use `:` for assigning a type to an attribute. I've got the code below that is correct but I'm not sure why I declare `React.FunctionComponent<Props>` and not `React.FunctionComonent : Props`

```
    interface Props {
        speakers : Speaker[]
    }

    const SpeakersMain : React.FunctionComponent<Props> = (props : Props) => (
        <div>
            <SpeakersHeader/>
            <SpeakerList speakers={props.speakers} />
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: You may want to start with pure TS before diving to React+TS. This is a generic, it's TS feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const SpeakersMain: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ...;
```

should be used because the use of `:` after `React.FunctionComponent` would be incorrect syntax.

`SpeakersMain: React.FunctionComponent` means that `SpeakersMain` variable is of `React.FunctionComponent` type. While `<Props>` adds the clarification to `React.FunctionComponent` because was defined as [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in React typings. `<>` syntax allows to pass `Props` as a parameter.

`React.FunctionComponent<Props>` type means that it's a function that gets `Props` type as its `props` parameter.

It works as:

```
type Foo<T = {}> = (props: T) => void;
type Bar = { bar: number };

var foo1: Foo = (props) => { /* props is supposed to be empty object by default */ };
var foo2: Foo<Bar> = (props) => { /* props is supposed to be Bar */ };
```

Comment: Thanks @estus  Makes sense. I'm a c# guy so should have known that. I had just not thought about in JavaScript making sense.  Kind of going from untyped to typed, then back to typing untyped again.

Comment: There is a lot of foreign looking syntax in TypeScript.  It's going to take me a while to figure out what are the "Good Parts"